# Bootstrap datetimepicker issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I had this datetimepicker working not too long ago, but now it's no longer opening. I did move it to a modal window, but it's still in the same file where I'm calling the JS and CSS files.

Here is what is in the head:

```
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
 <script type="text/javascript" 
       src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" 
       src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
 </head>
```

Here is the code that should call the datetimepicker, which is inside a modal window:

```
 <div class='input-append' id='datetimepicker'>
 <label>Delivery Appt Date</label>
 <input data-format='yyyy-MM-dd' type="text" 
       style="width: 140px;" value="" id="del_date" name="del_date" />
 <span class='add-on'>
 <i data-date-icon='icon-calendar' data-time-icon='icon-time'></i>
 </span>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
     pickTime: false
     });
 });
 </script>
 </div>
```

The i data-date tag above shows the little image of the calendar, so I know it's getting the CSS. But why doesn't it open the actual calendar window so the user can pick a date?

I've gone to several pages, and the closest thing I could find was this:  http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Those examples are the closest to what I have previously achieved, but for some reason, I cannot duplicate.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjq8U/), based on this [link](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

EDIT: fixed the fiddle link.

```
<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
       <label>Delivery Appt Date</label>
    <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text"  style="width: 140px;" value="" id="del_date" name="del_date" ></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      language: 'pt-EN'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: fiddle link is still broken!